# debugging Makefile how to suppress silence

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a way to suppress the silence '@' in the rules?
I want to see what the Makefile does but all rules from a given Makefile are defined with the '@' in front like:

```
go:
    @do something here...
```

I search for an option to see the output as `@` was not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `make` with the `-n` flag. You will be able to see which commands are executed. Without actually executing them though!

From GNU make manual:

> When make is given the flag ‘-n’ or ‘--just-print’ it only echoes most
>   recipes, without executing them. See Summary of Options. In this case
>   even the recipe lines starting with ‘@’ are printed. This flag is
>   useful for finding out which recipes make thinks are necessary without
>   actually doing them.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from using `-n` as suggested you could (if the makefile is under your control to edit) look at using something like my automake-inspired [silent make rules](https://github.com/deryni/silent-make-rules) stuff.

Which lets you override the silencing at `make` run time dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You might be willing to do this:

- At the top of the makefile, put `silence ?= @`
- Change all the `@`-prefixes to `$(silence)`.

Then `make` will observe the silences by default and `make silence=` will
be verbose.

If you don't want to do that, there's a pretty good chance that:

```
cat Makefile | sed 's/\t@/\t/g' | make -f -
```

will do the trick.